# Python: Save data in google cloud datastore emulator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am trying to test google's cloud datastore locally. My test steps are:

1. Crawl data using Scrapy
2. Save data to the cloud datastore using local emulator

I followed all the steps in order to use the local emulator

1. start local emulator: `gcloud beta emulators datastore start`
2. set local environment variables: `gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init`

However, in python, when use the following command to access cloud datastore, it always save the data directly to google cloud instead of saving them to the local emulators

```
#Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import datastore

# Instantiates a client
datastore_client = datastore.Client()

sample_entry = some_data

# Saves the entity
datastore_client.put(sample_entry)
```

It seems like you cannot specify the library to use the local datastore emulator, just like what they offer in their Node.js client

```
var datastore = gcloud.datastore({
        apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:8380"
});
```

My question is, How can I ask the google cloud datastore python library to use local emulator instead of using the cloud directly

Comment: What's the value of the `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable after you call `env-init`?

Comment: While I'm always one for local testing and dev serving, the Google Cloud environment is so hopelessly convoluted that I definitely wouldn't recommend using their platform emulation packages. Bugs like this, as well as inconsistencies in behavior with the actual deployment environment, make it a headache not worth having; unless there's a reason you can't, I'd suggest just using a staging project in the cloud environment.

Comment: Probably, you may want to double check your emulator setup following steps given in here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help you either: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1837

Answer (score 1):

You need to `eval $(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)`.

`gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init` only prints the commands that set the necessary environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
  # Production
else:
  # Local development server
```

You can follow more here, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server